# Reference request: Limits and Derivatives

Tags: calculus, limits, reference-request, derivatives

Could you recommend/suggest a good E-book about Limits and Derivatives  with exercise solutions

What do you think about that book [Limits and Derivatives Made Easy](http://books.google.co.ma/books?id=YJ21s52EGuUC&hl) ?

looks good but it's not available on E-book

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for practice problems on derivatives I would recommend going out and buying a cheap school textbook or maybe even like an AP practice book, they generally will have lots of examples and answers with explanations.

Comment: I prefer e-books so I can take it along with me and read whenever I get a chance.